# Global pointer set to NULL after calling yylex()

Tags: c, pointers, struct, flex-lexer

I have a problem of declaring a **global scope pointer**, in the definition part of my flex file, then i `malloc` it in the start of my main, but **as soon as my program runs into `yylex()`,** **the pointer's value is set to `NULL`**.

I need this pointer to a `struct` (this is `struct Modele * model`) all along my program, it's basically a pointer to the structure I store all my results from the file in, so I actually cannot do without it, at least not without a pointer to a struct which would work fine in both `main()` and `yylex()`.

On execution, the program runs into a segfault, trying to write at the adress 0x4 ; running the program under valgrind, and printing the value of `model` allowed me to understand that the memory was correctly allocated, but as soon as yylex was called, the value of `model` was `NULL` (printed `(nil)`). I don't use any header here, but i tried using one to store all my structures, and the declaration of my global scope variables, but without success.

**My question is : what did I do wrong to face such a behavior ?** And what is generally the best way not to have this problem ? I'm not sure I ever used global scope pointers, so it could be this, or maybe a flex-lex specific problem .... i'm a bit lost !

Here is a sample of my code :

```
%{

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//some more includes and #defines

typedef struct Doc {
    int classe;
    uint32_t * words;
    int current_index;
    int current_size;
} doc;

typedef struct Modele {
    int nb_classes;
    int nb_docs;
    int nb_docs_base;
    int nb_docs_test;
    int base_or_test;
    int voc_size;
    int M_test_size;
    liste ** M_theta;
    row_info * M_calc;
    doc * M_test;
} modele;
//some more typedefs

modele * model;  //             <--- this is the pointer i talk about

//some more functions bodies .....
%}

couple_entiers      [0-9]+:[0-9]+
// .......
%%

{couple_entiers} { model->nb_docs ++}
//.....

%%

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // .....
    modele * model = malloc(sizeof model); //    <---- here is the malloc
    model->nb_classes = 0;
    model->nb_docs = 0;
    model->nb_docs_base = 0;
    model->nb_docs_test = 0;
    model->voc_size = 0;
    model->M_test = malloc (TAB_SIZE * sizeof(doc));
    //....
    if ((yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL){
            printf("Impossible d'ouvrir %s !\n",argv[1]);
            exit(0);    
        }

        yylex();
```

In case that piece of code is not enough to grab the origin of the problem, i'll paste more of it, I just wanted to select the relevant parts.

Comment: You can change the prototype of `yylex` by defining the `YY_DECL` macro. So you don't need to rely on a global variable if you dislike global variables, as many of us do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is : what did I do wrong to face such a behavior ?

You never did set the file-scope variable.  Your `main()` function instead declares and initializes a *local* variable of the same name and type.  The local declaration "shadows" the file-scope one within its scope.

To fix it, just change this ...

```
    modele * model = malloc(sizeof model);
```

... to this:

```
    model = malloc(sizeof model);
```

If you do not precede the variable name with a type then you are referring to a variable declared elsewhere (in this case, at file scope).

Comment: To add: OP should always enable recommended warnings which includes `-Wshadow` (gcc, other compilers might use a different option).

Comment: damn right, a stupid mistake which actually did cost me some time .... thanks a lot !